# Unisharp laravel filemanager unable to 'browse server' in ckeditor

Tags: php, laravel, file-manager

I have been trying to apply [Unisharp Laravel Filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager). But, the issue I am facing is that when ever I try to insert image in CKeditor and click on the <kbd>Browse Server</kbd> button, a new window pops up with an HTTP 404 error response code saying:

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

I have followed all the steps as mentioned in the docs of Unisharp Laravel Filemanager for installation and integration. Also I am using Laravel 5.4 and [Unisharp FileManager 1.6](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/releases/tag/1.6.0) (released August 2016).

What is causing this 404 error and how can I correct it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the lfm.php file the very first setting is a routes setting. That needs to be changed from false to true.

Comment: Thank u for trying to help me. But, routes setting has already 'true' value set. If there is any other possibility,,then please let me know.. thanks again

Comment: I have tried to install file manager package once again in a fresh laravel project..the issue is still the same. please help me

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the following lines were added before App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class, on the config/app.php

```
 Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,
 Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

then.

1. Make sure lfm.php is present in config folder.
2. Make sure the routes were loaded by running php artisan route:list

if you followed the installation guide and those are not present use php artisan config:cache then run the two vendor publish command on the guide

Hope this helps